# Check email id real or fake in AngularJS project

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, express, nodemailer

I have a web project in AngularJS and using NOdeJS and ExpressJS on Backend.
I have a contact form in my application when I click on submit form data is sent as an email. This I have achieved using `npm` package called `nodemailer`.

But, now I wanted to check if that email id exists in real world (fake or real) before sending an email. So what is the best way to achieve this?

Can any one help me with this?

Thank you

Comment: You should have verified email id before sending mail. It will give error for first time but next time onwards you can know that its not valid in case of invalid email address.

Comment: I know that we need to have verified email id before sending mail. I'm saying in my application I have a contact me form. I get an email when user clicks on submit button along with whatever user has entered. Now I'm asking if user enters invalid email id and clicks submit then I should not get an email at all.

Comment: @AshwathSH You need this kind of tool http://email-checker.net/  And I cannot imagine that someone would use this for anything but spamming. Also, any decent mail provider should protect their customers against such abuse. For good intentions regexp matching and checking for domain existence is enough.

Answer (score 1):

There are some open source api like http://api.mailtest.in/v1/XXX

Where XXX is the domain from email. Which means if XXX exists as domain you can assume that mailbox might exist. Try using curl / parser to fetch the response via api call if its true means domain exists and email might exist as well.

Comment: This is a good option but what if someone tries to enter xxx@gmail.com and if this does not exist, but still this api says as `ACTIVE`. So is there any way that I can figure out?

Answer (score 0):

Theoratically its possible by actually sending email and verifying the response itself. Check this https://github.com/hbattat/verifyEmail

But still there are certain conditions, many times the responses are not being sent by Mail Exchange servers for security reasons. Also your email can be blacklisted by doing this.

The real world scenario might be simple with user interaction, send email and ask them to verify their mail using the secret shared in email.

Comment: also check this https://mailboxlayer.com/ it does pretty same by showing SMTP / MX record existence.